# Use wireshark to detect problems with webRTC

Tags: webrtc, wireshark

so i started to work in this summer and the first task they have given to me is to use wireshark to understand why an application that uses webRTC doesn't use the turn server.
Can you guys help me out, to understand which steps should i do to understand better where is the problem.
I already run the wireshark and only get protocols STUN, that bind to a UDP connection.

Answer (score 6):

TURN is a STUN extension so you will only see STUN packets in Wireshark.

You can easily test WebRTC+TURN in isolation using [this sample](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/) from the WebRTC project. Remove the default stun server and add the url and credentials for your own TURN server.
Fire up wireshark, start capturing.

Click the "gather candidates" button on that page. You should see candidates with host type at least. You should, if the browser can reach the TURN server usually also see candidates with a srflx type.
If the TURN server is working and your credentials are valid, then you will get candidates with type relay. But you probably wouldn't be asking then.

Now go back to wireshark. Set the display filter to 'stun'. You should see some packets sent to the ip address of the TURN server. Right-click on one of them, 'follow' and 'udp stream'. That should show you all the packets between the browser and the TURN server.
You should be seeing binding requests (message_type=0x01) as well as binding success responses (message_type=0x101) from the server. If you don't see those, your turn server is not responding or something is blocking the client. You will also not get srflx candidates on the candidate gathering demo page.

You should also see packets wireshark interprets as 'allocate request udp' (the message type is 0x101). These are the important ones for TURN.
You should see an error from the TURN server with a message type 0x113 and an error code 401 (unauthorized) because in the first packets, there is no username attribute. In response to those the browser will start sending allocate requests that contain both a username and a message-integrity.
If things go well, those should be answered with an allocate success response (message type=0x103) indicating a xor-relayed-address.

If not and you see more 401 errors that usually means your username and password is wrong.

You might also find the articles on using wireshark to reverse-engineer [Amazon Mayday](https://webrtchacks.com/mayday-trace/) and [Whatsapp](https://webrtchacks.com/whats-up-with-whatsapp-and-webrtc/) on WebRTChacks useful -- both use Wireshark.

The WebRTC project has [some notes](https://webrtc.github.io/webrtc-org/testing/wireshark/) on Wireshark, too.